# why acitivies have to be registered in manifest file

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

we worked for exam with our friends. I tried to explain manifest file, talking about how to do things. But I see that I did know why to register activities to androidManifest.xml. Still do not know :). Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: thanks for recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifest file is used by the system to know what kind of components do the application have. Without registering your `Activities`/`Services`/`Receivers`/`Content Providers` the system would have to scan and parse the whole apk every time someone wants to use a specific component to find it. This would be really slow, that's why there is the `AndroidManifest.xml`, which is a small file, and it can be parsed fast to find the required component.

Answer (score 0):

Manifest file describes the following features...

1. Version Number and Version Code:
   This is useful, when you are uploading the application in Google play or go for upgrade the existing published apk.

2.minSdk and targetSdk:
mentioned your min and max version number your application supports.

3.application tag:
used to set the first activity or home activity when you launch an application from laucher.

4.activity tag:
the list of all activities in the application declared as child tag in application tag for the easier navigation to activity manager.

When we switch one activity to another activity, the activity manager checks whether this activity is declared in manifest file or not. If not found throws exception.

Uses: Developer can have look at all the activities at a glance (By Manifest file)

5.Filter tags: By intent filters in activity tag, User can open any kind of application activity.

1. Uses permission and Uses features:
   All application resources are declared here.
   example: Internet connectivity is needed for your application, Uses WIFI in your application.

Comment: for your 4th option: I think it is not the reason. it's about what if you do not do it. thanks for answer though